# how do I integrate a modulus function. is it possible?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am solving a question in which after calculating, my instantaneous velocity is  $f(t)=\frac{ab\sin(bt)}{\sqrt{2-2\cos(bt)}}$.

So I need to find distance in time $T$. For finding distance I need to take its modulus and integrate
$|f(t)|$dt.

So how do I find integral of
$|f(t)|$dt.
Any hints are appreciable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that a and b are POSITIVE constants.

Comment: Is the instantaneous velocity $f(t)$ always positive?

Comment: No how it will if sinbt becomes negative. That is why I have to take its modulus.

Comment: If you multiply both top and bottom by $\sqrt{2+2\cos(bt)}$ you might get something more workable.

Comment: Perhaps the physical context of the problem imposes $T<\pi/b$ in which case $|f(t)|=f(t)$ in the integrand.

Comment: It is not mentioned here or they would have simply asked for displacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \left| \frac{ab\sin bt}{\sqrt{2-2\cos bt}} \right| &=
  \left|
    \frac{2ab\sin \frac{bt}{2} \cos \frac{bt}{2}}{\sqrt{4\sin^{2} \frac{bt}{2}}}
  \right| \\
  &= \left| ab\cos \frac{bt}{2} \right| \\
 s &= \int_{0}^{t} \left| ab\cos \frac{bt}{2} \right| dt \\
   &= 2a E \left( \frac{bt}{2}, 1 \right)
\end{align*}

> where $\displaystyle E(\theta,k)=\int_{0}^{\theta} \sqrt{1-k^{2} \sin^{2} \phi} \, d\phi$ is the elliptic integral of the second kind.
>
> In this case, $$E \left( \frac{bt}{2},1 \right)=
> 2\left \lfloor \frac{bt}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor+
> (-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{bt}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor} \sin \frac{bt}{2}$$

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it. What is elliptic integral?

Comment: In short, it's used for calculating arc length of an ellipse.  Here, it's used to avoid discontinuity in $s$.  Alternately, $$E(t,1)=2\left \lfloor \frac{t}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor+(-1)^{\left \lfloor \frac{t}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2} \right \rfloor} \sin t$$